# How to query store in ember object?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am following this tutorial to http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/07/08/authentication-with-emberjs-part-2/ implement authentication. But i am not able to access the store in auth manager. Its failing while doing User.find(userId).

I have ember 1.13 and ember-data 1.13.8

Comment: That is a very old blog post. I suggest finding a newer one on the topic, or use something like [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth).

Comment: And really, really use ember-cli!

Comment: Also, it's hard to help without showing us any of your code.